# "Not only can I not help you, but also (never/ under no circumstances) can our parents help you."

Tags: inversion

Is my sentence grammatically correct?

> Not only can I not help you, but also (never/ under no circumstances) can our parents help you.

Comment: In those 'not only ... but also ...' phrases you can't have one part positive and one part negative, because both phrases have to have the same 'vibe', they both have to have roughly the same meaning.

Comment: Dear @JacobLee-Hart thanks for comments, it was a fruitful hint to me. I edited, now do you thinks it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't really sound right to phrase it like that. A good alternative would be:

> Not only can I not help you, but our parents can't help you either under any circumstances

or

> Not only can I not help you, but nor can our parents under any circumstances

It sounds more natural to put the negative with the verb 'can' rather than in the 'any circumstances' phrase.

Comment: according to your opinion, the sentence of "Not only can I not help you, but also never can our parents help you." is also incorrect and unnatural?

Comment: It doesn't sound quite right to me. But also only sounds right with positive statements rather than negative ones. 'either' is doing the same sort of role as 'also' but for a negative sentence in my first example.

Comment: but our parents can't help you **either** under etc.

Comment: Fair comment, if you have either at the end it means that 'under any circumstances' applies to 'I' and 'our parents'.